# JQuery addClass to thumbnail when slide is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm building a slider functionality from scratch. I have a list of slides and the current slide has a class of "active-slide."

```
<ul class="slides">
   <li class ="active-slide"></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

I then have a list of corresponding thumbnails that when you click on them the slider shows the corresponding slide.

```
 <ul class="thumbnails">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

All of this is working properly and the slider changes slides and adds the class "active-slide".
What I'm trying to do is listen for the class of "active-slide" and then add a class of "active-thumb" to the corresponding thumbnail so that the user knows which thumbnail is currently activated. The slider is using previous, next, as well as pagination so it's crcial that I'm always listening for the "active-slide" as it changes every 10 seconds.

I'm using Backbones.js and can't quite to seem how to check for the active slide index and then add the class of "active-thumb" to the corresponding/matching index of the active thumbnail.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't listen for classes. You listen for events. You should change your slider function to trigger a custom event when the active index changes and have your thumbnails bind to it.

Comment: Please provide the minimal code required to reproduce, or an online demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom attribute.

```
<ul class="slides">
   <li data-index="1" class ="active-slide"></li>
   <li data-index="2"></li>
   <li data-index="3"></li>
   <li data-index="4"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="thumbnails">
   <li data-index="1"></li>
   <li data-index="2"></li>
   <li data-index="3"></li>
   <li data-index="4"></li>
</ul>
```

When you click next or prev :

```
$(".thumbnails [data-index='" + $('.slides .active-slide').attr('data-index') + "']").addClass("active-thumb");
```

Code not tested but i think you get the idea.

**Edit :**

To remove the active. Save the current index. Remove all the active and apply the active again with the current index previously saved.

```
// assume we click next
var currentIndex = $('.slides .active-slide').attr('data-index');
$(".thumbnails li").removeClass("active-thumb");
$(".thumbnails [data-index='" + (currentIndex + 1) + "']").addClass("active-thumb");
```

Of course, you need a little bit more to check if your at the end or the begening of the slide but i'm sure you can handle that.

Comment: I got this working on previous and next as you mentioned, but how would you suggest removing the class to the thumbnail when the active slide has changed? Also, the slider is auto playing, so what would be the best way to be running this check at all times?

Comment: The next and the interval of the slider should call the same function wich manage the active-slide and tumbnails.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you or to manage the add and remove class.